# Reducing size of input in form group

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following set up so far [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sq9Xy/19/). I am hoping to reduce the size of the `Cost Codes` input box to leave room for another input box on the right that may or may not be there.

The input box that might appear on the right will show up dynamically depending on what the user puts in the `Cost Code` box, so I am looking for a solution that would work whether that input is there or not. But I am having trouble getting it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stick a `col-xs-6` class on the form group div. Also make sure there's a div with the class of `row` around it.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="create-enter-code1" placeholder="Cost Code">
    </div>
<!-- insert another div here -->
</div>
```

Comment: Nest the `form-group` inside the `col-xs-3` div. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/sq9Xy/23/

Comment: You removed your secondary question, but I hope that helped

Answer (score 0):

In your stylesheet:

```
#create-enter-code1{
    width:50%;
}
```